# Enzyme mount tests on native-base components

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, enzyme, native-base

I was trying to use enzyme mount to test some composite components. But I got an error message

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

The LoginScreen is exported as a default class so the way I import the class is correct.
And then I tested every single component in the LoginScreen class and I realized that the test only fails at the native-base components. But I wasn't sure about the reason and there is no documentation on explaining this situation.

The tests on failed on the five components below.

```
import { Form, Icon, Input, Item, Label } from "native-base";
```

```
import React from 'react';
import LoginScreen from "../../src/views/LoginScreen/index";
import { mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import {TesterUtils} from "../__utils__/Tester";
import {Provider} from "mobx-react/custom";
import {RootServiceInjector} from "../../src/services/injection";


describe("login function with mount", () => {
    it("try with mount", () => {
        const testerUtils = new TesterUtils();
        const rootService = testerUtils.getServiceRoot();
        const wrapper = mount(
            <Provider {...{[RootServiceInjector]: rootService}}>
                <LoginScreen/>
            </Provider>
        );
    });
});
```

Is there anyone else who has encountered with this issue and has a solution? 
Thank you so much!

Comment: I am facing the same issue currently.